# 5 card selection from bundle

Tags: combinatorics

Determine in how many ways you can select 5 cards from a standard 52-card bundle, and  each color is chosen among your selections.

The standard set of cards contains 13 different cards in 4 colors.

I am looking for solution of this.

My idea is

$${\binom{13}{1}  \binom{13}{1} \binom{13}{1} \binom{13}{2} }$$

Disclaimer: this is not a homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost there. One more thing you should consider is that the color including $2$ cards can be chosen from $4$ different colors as well (which color will have $2$ cards?). This makes the answer
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{13}{1}  \binom{13}{1} \binom{13}{1} \binom{13}{2}$$